# HTML & CSS - I'm having trouble trying to create a square shape from rounds

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make the following shape with HTML and CSS:

[image]

I tried to do this with HTML and CSS but with the code I wrote, I got the following image:

[image]

This is my homework and I can't get the round shapes down that should be below. How can I do that? Thanks in advance for your help.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 250px;
  width: 250px;
  background-color: grey;
}

.box {
  background-color: red;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50px;
}

.left-flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  float: left;
}

.right-flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  float: right;
}

.top-flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-items: start;
}

.bottom-flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-items: end;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left-flex">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="right-flex">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="top-flex">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="bottom-flex">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you supposed to be using `display: flex`? This seems like something for which `display: grid` would be more appropriate. Regardless, see [A Complete Guide to Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) and [A Complete Guide to Grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplify your code and think in rows. The 3 center rows have only 2 boxes. Then space them apart with `justify-content: space-between`

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: grey;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.container,
.row {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.box {
  background-color: red;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

EDIT: If you want to do the spacings, add the same flexbox and `justify-content: space-between` to the container. Just change the `flex-direction` to `column`. If you make the container then wider and taller, you create equal gaps by default.